# Ubuntu Server with gma500 graphics

Tags: gma500

I’m having major issues getting any version of Ubuntu Server to work on my device. My NAS, a QNAP TS-869 Pro, has an Intel Atom D2700 and GMA500 graphics. Basically, I have read about the lack of drivers but just need my system to display console text. Nothing more really - currently I just get a black screen.

Any suggestions regarding what distribution might work? Or would certain GRUB settings help? Would it make any difference trying a 32 but version? I did, some years ago, have it working but I cannot remember the Ubuntu version I used.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Exactly when do you get a black screen. Have you been able to install? Assuming you can change grub options, `nomodset` might help.

Comment: I cannot even install, it goes black just after seeing the message ‘gma500 - gpu- power management timed out’. The previous LTS version did the same but the graphics worked enough to install, but then the graphics went blank after completing install and rebooting. Unfortunately when powering off, it does not always work and I need to hold down the power button... Then, it will not boot but without graphics I can’t see the issue. Thanks

Comment: Any further suggestions? Grub shows up, however I’m still loosing video once it boots. I’ve blacklisted the ‘gma500_gfx’ driver and tried ‘nomodeset’ and still no luck. Now, my server boots and lets me ping it but SSH and SMB are not functioning.

Comment: Not sure what's wrong. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt see the answer here but I had a smilar problem with my netbook. Go to advanced boot options and disable acpi. This show allow the NAS to boot and display on screen. Hope this helps.